# Django: how to get the current user's group id

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-views

I am wondering how can I get the current user id in the views.py? Furthermore, how can I get the current user's group id? Do I have to directly query the database using the user id? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

View functions get `request` as one of their parameters. Assuming you're using the built in auth app, the current user (if any) will be `request.user`. This may be a representation of an [anonymous user](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.user) if the session does not have a logged-in user - see the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/default/#limiting-access-to-logged-in-users) if you don't want to allow that.

Users can be in many groups, so I'm not quite sure what you mean by "group id". The user's groups are available as a standard many-to-many field, as `request.user.groups`. That's a manager object, so you can apply filters and such to it - to get them all, `request.user.groups.all()`.

Comment: Thanks! I need the group id because I have extended the group models, so I think I would need the group id to get field values out. But with request.user.groups.all(), it seems that it only returns the name of the group...

Comment: `groups.all()` returns the actual `Group` objects. If you `print` it they will be represented using their names, but `groups.all()[0].somefield` should also work. Unless your extensions to the models have changed the relationship. You need to show your custom model code in your question if that's the case.

Comment: Hey man, I have another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19898284/django-why-the-manytomany-choice-box-only-has-on-side won't you help me with it?

Answer (score 6):

```
user = auth.get_user(request)
group = request.user.groups.values_list('name', flat=True).first()
```

Works Perfect!

So u can replace **'name'** with **'id'** to get group's ID

Answer (score 0):

If there is one and only one group per user in your use case, you can get that group by using `request.user.groups.get()`. `objects.get()` works somewhat similar to `objects.all()[0]`. So it will fail when there are more than one group for that user.

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/query.py

```
def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Performs the query and returns a single object matching the given
    keyword arguments.
    """
    clone = self.filter(*args, **kwargs)
    if self.query.can_filter():
        clone = clone.order_by()
    clone = clone[:MAX_GET_RESULTS + 1]
    num = len(clone)
    if num == 1:
        return clone._result_cache[0]
    if not num:
        raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
            "%s matching query does not exist." %
            self.model._meta.object_name)
    raise self.model.MultipleObjectsReturned(
        "get() returned more than one %s -- it returned %s!" % (
            self.model._meta.object_name,
            num if num <= MAX_GET_RESULTS else 'more than %s' % MAX_GET_RESULTS
        )
    )
```

If you are after categorising your users, just extend the user model and set a foreign key field. Using permission groups for that matter doesn't seem like a good approach to me.

Answer (score 0):

If you debug with the break point on the method below,

```py
@csrf_exempt
def auth_check(request):
    return HttpResponse(str(request.user)) # <- breakpoint
```

you can see that there are `user.groups` in the request.

[image: Imgur]

As shown in the highlighted part above, you can find the groups name to which the user belongs.

you can easily get user group id

```py
request.user.groups.name
```